# Disable drag and drop for WebView in favor for one of its superviews

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, rubymotion

I'm working on an application featured like Mac Mail. I have a WebView which allow the user to write a new message. I implemented the drag and drop feature so that a user can add an attachment to the message that way.

To make it simple, I have a main view which contains a WebView and other views. I implemented the drag and drop on this main view (with the draggingEntered: and performDragOperation: methods) and it works as expected.

The problem is that by default, when dragging a file inside a WebView, an image for instance, the image will be displayed in the WebView. But I don't want that, I want it to be added as an attachment, that's why I disabled the drag and drop inside the WebView:

```rb
  def webView(sender, dragDestinationActionMaskForDraggingInfo:draggingInfo)
    WebDragDestinationActionNone
  end
```

But now my file will be added as an attachment if I drag it anywhere inside the main view, except in the WebView (the draggingEntered: and performDragOperation: methods are not called in this case).

I don't know if my question is clear enough to find an answer, I am still new in Cocoa development, so don't hesitate to tell me  if you need more details. Another thing, i'm working with Rubymotion but if you got a solution in Objective-C, that would also be perfect!

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

**Solution**

I subclassed the WebView and overrode the `performDragOperation` method to make it work:

```
def performDragOperation(sender)
  self.UIDelegate.mainView.performDragOperation(sender)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `sender` (which implements the `NSDraggingInfo` protocol) for the destination window:

http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDraggingInfo/draggingDestinationWindow

```
def performDragOperation(sender)
  if sender.draggingDestinationWindow == @web_view
    # Attach file
  else
    # Let it do the normal drag operation
  end
  true
end
```

That's just a guess, but you should be able to figure out a solution from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't use the draggingDestinationWindow method but was able to solve the problem by subclassing the webview and overriding the performDragOperation method, helped by this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742276/drag-and-drop-from-finder-to-webview. But you put me on the right way so I'll accept you answer.